# Calling Inherited Class Specific Functions in C++

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have the following problem. I am busy coding up an inheritance structure in C++. Briefly, this is what I am attempting to do. Class A is the base class and classes B and C are inherited class. Classes B and C each have different and unique member functions.

Now, using the boost smart pointer library I make a vector of shared pointer of class type A as follows:

```
class A{
   A();
   virtual print();
}

class B : public A{
   B();
   virtual print();
}

class C{
   C();
   virtual print();
   void uniqueFunc();
}

int main(){

  vector<shared_ptr<A> > myA;
  shared_ptr<B> myB;
  shared_ptr<C> myC;

  myA.push_back(myB);
  myA.push_back(myC);

}
```

Now I have a method for checking the type of members within the vector. This isn't the issue. My question is, how do I call uniqueFunc for a member of class type C within the vector. Would I have to downcast? Or do I have to create virtual function. I do however, need uniqueFunc to be unique to class C. I would like to avoid creating copies of members and rather directly change the member in the vector.

Comment: I assume you meant C to inherit from either A or B in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to downcast to `boost::shared_ptr<C>` or create a virtual function in `A`.

Assuming you want to downcast, you could use Boost's [pointer cast functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/pointer_cast.html):

```
boost::static_pointer_cast<C>(myA.back())->uniqueFunc();
```

(or use `dynamic_pointer_cast<C>` if you need dynamic type checking.)